# When using a NSTimer in Objective-C, why isn't my code stopping when it gets to 0?

Tags: objective-c

I am using a timer in xcode i have managed to make it count down correctly but when counting down it goes into negatives,

i have tried using an if statement to counter this but it dosnt seem to work here is the code i am using,

```
    IBOutlet UILabel *timelabel;
    int MainInt;
    NSInteger fred;
    NSTimer *timer;



    MainInt -= 1;
    timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",MainInt ];

    MainInt = 20;
    timer  = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    if (timelabel.text <= @"0")
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timelabel.text = @"20";
    }
```

the H is ov my H

Comment: where is countdown function? paste it here

Comment: even if it is obvious what H is I will recommend to separate the two code snippets for better visibility. We don't know what the content of countdown is. And last don't compare the string but MainInt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I believe it would compile

```
if (timelabel.text <= @"0")
```

This line doesn't make much sense. It should probably read:

```
if(MainInt <= 0)
```

Comment: Prefect, its simple when you think about it like that (that goes for jack aswell) but since it was james answer i used Cheers buddy

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to compare the text value of the label with zero, compare `MainInt`. Your problem is that you're trying to compare two strings... Technically, you can get the ASCII value of a character and compare it to another, so basically you tried to do something like `@"Dog" >= @"Cat"` which the runtime will attempt to do but obviously isn't what you want.

There's also a method on `NSString` called `intValue` that you could use to pull out an integer representation of the string. You could do

> if ([timelabel.text intValue] <= 0)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check the timelabel.text use the intValue

```
 if ([timelabel.text intValue] <= 0) 
 {
    timer invalidate];
    timelabel.text = @"20";
 }
```

Note: Change to intValue, but take note you should compare it to `int` also